# JavaScript: Making a simple search engine which searches through <h3> elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple search engine that compares user input to a bunch of  elements in an html document, the idea being that the  elements are movie titles.

When a user types in a movie title completely or partially, the script should find the nearest matching title and highlight it using style.Backgroundcolor. I have been trying to do it like this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" title="Zoekbalk" id="userinput" placeholder="Typ hier om te zoeken" class="input_box" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('search_button').click()"/>

<input class="search_button" onsubmit="return false;" type="button" value="Zoek" id="search_button" onclick="Search()"/>
```

JS

```
function Search() {
    userinput = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
    if (!userinput.replace(/\s+/g, '')) {
        alert('U heeft geen zoekterm ingevuld!');
        return;
    }

    // userinput = userinput.toLowerCase(); 
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
    var i = list.length, html, flag = false, matches = []; 

    while (i--)
    {
        var html = list[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase;
        if (-1 < html.indexOf(userinput))
        {
            flag = true;
            matches.push(html);
        }
    }

    if (!flag)
    {
        alert('No match found !');
    }
    else 
    {
        alert('Matched: ' + matches.join(', '));
        matches.style.backgroundColor = "#ff6d6d";
        matches.scrollIntoView();
    }
};
```

The problem is this: The first If() which checks if the user has actually filled in anything works perfectly fine. But if I do fill in anything at all, nothing happens! I took a look in the Chrome Debug console and it said that it had found an uncaught type error at line 22 of my JS (which is the first if statement after the While() loop).

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to invoke the toLowerCase function in the assignment of the html variable?

Comment: What @STT said (you need `.toLowerCase()`), but also `matches` is an array and therefore has no `style` attribute, nor `scrollIntoView()` method. You want `matches[0].style` and `matches[0].scrollIntoView()`

Comment: SST and Absol, you were right! Thanks a lot for helping me, I will make sure to look out for this obvious mistake in the future.

Comment: `while (i--)` gives me goosebumps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.  Some of your mistakes are:

- the `toLowerCase` method without parentheses
- the `matches` array stores DOM elements, but you try to get strings from there
- trying to apply a `style` to an array!
- also trying to use `scrollIntoView` on an array!

This code works:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");

function Search() {
    var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput").value;

    if (!userinput.replace(/\s+/g, '')) {
      alert('U heeft geen zoekterm ingevuld!');
      return;
    }

    userinput = userinput.toLowerCase();

    var count = list.length, html, flag = false, matches = [], stringMatches = [];

    while (count--)
    {
      html = list[count].innerHTML.toLowerCase();

      if (-1 < html.indexOf(userinput))
      {
        flag = true;
        matches.push(list[count]);
        stringMatches.push(list[count].innerHTML.toLowerCase());
      }
    }

    if (!flag) {
      alert('No match found !');
    }
    else {
      alert('Matched: ' + stringMatches.join(', '));
      for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        matches[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6d6d";
        if (i === 0)
          matches[i].scrollIntoView();
      }
    }
  }
```

http://jsbin.com/tohecakojaji/1/edit

Performance tip: put the `list` variable outside of the Search function, to avoid traversing the DOM on every click.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of problems in your code. The most obvious is that `toLowerCase` is a method so you must invoke it.

Another mistake is that `matches.style.backgroundColor = "#ff6d6d";` makes no sense, since `matches` is the array of strings. Below is fixed code:

```
function Search() {

    var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput").value.toLowerCase();
    if (!userinput.replace(/\s+/g, '')) {
        alert('U heeft geen zoekterm ingevuld!');
        return;
    }

    clear();

    // userinput = userinput.toLowerCase(); //we converteren de user userinput naar LowerCase
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("h3"); //dit wordt de lijst met titels
    var i = list.length,
        html, flag = false,
        matches = []; //hier maken we vars/arrays voor het loopen en returnen van output aan

    while (i--) //we loopen door de list net zolang als die lang is (i = lengte v.d. lijst)
    {
        var html = list[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
        if (-1 < html.indexOf(userinput)) //als er een match is word 'flag' true
        {
            flag = true;
            matches.push(list[i]); //de desbetreffende titel wordt in de lege array matches[] gezet
            list[i].className = "matched";
        }
    }

    if (!flag) {
        alert('No match found !');
    } 
    else {
        alert('Matched');
        //matches.scrollIntoView();
    }
}

function clear() {
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         list[i].className = '';
    }
}
```

I also added `clear` function to remove highlights from previous search, and made use of CSS class instead of `style.backgroundColor` for best practices.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gm7uofj6/